# Unable to access Tomcat manager and deployed application

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu server, installed Tomcat 7. I'm succesfully able to connect. I am able to access examples and docs. I deployed a java application, its returns http 404 status.

When trying to access manager webapp and host-manager webapp it is prompting for username and password. I have configured conf/tomcat-user.xml like below:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat, manager-gui"/>
```

I am unable to access using: username "tomcat" and password "tomcat", the authentication required popup is shown continuously.

Comment: same issue after removing the space